# Why doesn't my screen turn red?

Tags: java

Ok, so I'm new to programming and I'm following a tutorial on Youtube to build my own game. My problem is that my screen doesn't turn red, it just stays gray. I'm sure I did something wrong but there are no errors on eclipse. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game() {
       Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
       setPreferredSize(size);

       frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread("Display");
        thread.start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
        thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();
        }

    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("JJF");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to turn black ?

Comment: Indeed, why? The only color that I see mentioned in your source code is `Color.RED`

Comment: Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

sorry i ment red i changed it

Comment: You don't have a paint method anywhere, or a typical game panel.

Comment: Alright, I am unsure what that is but in the tutorial I am watching I followed all the steps and he had his screen changing colors? mine will not though

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The OP is using a `BufferStrategy` which gives them direct access to the painting surface.  This is an example of active painting as apposed to the passive painting approach used by Swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually provide the `Thread` with something to run...

```
public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    // Not the reference to this...
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();

}
```

By passing `this` (which is an instance of your `Game` class which implements `Runnable`), the `Thread` will be able to call your `run` method

nb:

The size of your viewable area should be defined by the component, not the frame.  This can be achieved by overriding the `getPreferredSize` method and returning the preferred viewable size you want the component to be.  Otherwise, the viewable area will be the size of the frame minus it's decoration insets, which may not meet your expectations.

In your "game-loop" you should consider having a small delay between cycles to give time for the system to actually update the screen, this takes some of the pressure of the `Thread`

**Runnable example**

[image: Buffer]

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(40);
//          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//          }
        }

    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("JJF");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I added that but the result is still the same as before, when I run it, it doesn't seem to change colors

Comment: Works fine for me...make sure you've recompiled it and aren't using an old/dirty build

Comment: nevermind, I ran it again and got it thank you for the help, I must have forgot that during the tutorial!