# canvas would not draw in java

Tags: java, canvas

there seem to be something that i miss. or that i did not fully understand how canvas work in java. the problem is that canvas did not create anything. in the code below i know that canvas are working and showing because the background color have change into light blue but it should have also add a small red box inside that canvas. My goal for now is to have the canvas to show that small box.

// frame
    private static JFrame frame;

```
private static BufferStrategy bs;
private static Graphics g; 
private static JPanel jp;
private static Canvas canvas;
private static int width = 1000;
private static int height = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    locX.clear();
    locY.clear();

    loadData();


    createFrame();

}   

public static void createFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    canvas.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    //jp.setSize(new Dimension(width,height));

    //frame.add(jp);
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();

    bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(1);
        return;
    }

    g =  bs.getDrawGraphics();
    // clear screen
    //g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(400, 50, 100, 100);
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It’s possible that between you requesting the frame to become visible and you painting on the canvas, that it’s not yet attached to a native peer

Comment: You might need to paint the buffer a few times at first before it appears - maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000635/why-doesnt-my-screen-turn-red/29000677#29000677

Comment: Try removing g.dispose. Also, I would highly recommend not using Java, or at least switch over to Lwjgl. C# + OpenTK is a Titan.

Comment: you got it right Mad Programmer. Thank you

Comment: why do you not recommend on using java for this? can java become too complicated in creating a game??

Comment: My reasons are highly subjective, but I used Java for over eight years before C#. I could never go back to Java, even for something simple like a hello world. C# is 'Java Done Right'. As a technical example though, C# has Structs, which Java does not, nor does it have any value type, save for integers, etc. C# also has signed and unsigned integers. On top of that, C# has a fantastic coding standard. And WPF(which is like Java Swing) uses DirectX under the hood.